# bug in jukebox code (head first C)

Tags: c

I'm studying C programming with Head First C book.
So I'm trying to compile this code that we can find at page 94:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char tracks[][80] = {
    "I left my heart in Harvard Mead School",
    "Newark, Newark - a wonderful town",
    "Dancing with a Dork",
    "From here to maternity",
    "The girl from Iwo Jima",
};

void find_track(char search_for[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (strstr(tracks[i], search_for))
            printf("Track %i: '%s'\n", i, tracks[i]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char search_for[80];

    printf("Search for: ");
    fgets(search_for, 80, stdin);
    find_track(search_for);
    return 0;
}
```

Look at this output:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
./jukebox                                                      --
Search for: town                                               --
kawaban9a-14H:~/Code/C/Head_C/Chapter_3$ (so, nothing happens) --
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

It's ok, no compiler complaint, but when I run it, there's no result.
I read this code several times and I can't understand why, where's the bug?
If someone could help me with this, I'll be grateful.

SOME MINUTES LATER ...

Thank you friend cnicutar for your answer that helped me figure out the problem with `'\n'`.
I solved this problem by just inserting a piece of code before the call to the `find_track()` function.

Check it out:

```
int main(void)
{
    char search_for[80];

    printf("Search for: ");
    fgets(search_for, 80, stdin);

    size_t ln = strlen(search_for) - 1;
    if (search_for[ln] == '\n')
        search_for[ln] = '\0';

    find_track(search_for);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C Code for String matching\[Head First C\] doesn't seem to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019607/c-code-for-string-matchinghead-first-c-doesnt-seem-to-work)

Comment: I asked it today so check the answer. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27720837/no-output-in-terminal-head-first-c)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `fgets` stores the newline in the destination string. So your `strstr` needs to find `"town\n"`. One solution would be to trim `search_for` after  `fgets` to get rid of the newline.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `fgets` with:

```
scanf("%79s", search_for);
```

Comment: To improve your answers, please format them and provide explanations.