# No output in terminal (Head First C)

Tags: c

I was going through some exercises from the Head First C book. And there's one jukeBox program. 
Source is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char tracks[][80] = {
    "I left my heart in Harvard Med School",
    "Newark, Newark - a wonderful town",
    "Dancing with a Dork",
    "From here to maternity",
    "The girl from Iwo Jima",
};

void find_track(char search_for[]){
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if ( strstr(tracks[i], search_for) )
            printf("Track %i: '%s'\n", i, tracks[i]);
    }
}
int main(){
    char search_for[80];
    printf("Search for: ");
    fgets(search_for, 80, stdin);
    find_track(search_for);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using terminal to compile and see output of the program with gcc version 4.8.2 like:

```
gcc pr.c -o pr
```

And whenever I try to run the program and enter search string I get no output. Program just finishes execution and exits.

Also I want to mention that I tried to compile this code on ideone.com [here](http://ideone.com/yeSusJ). 
What problems there might be? Terminal displays no output at all.

Comment: there might be several different problems so it would be better to try with step-by-step debugging and observe the behaviour. A first guess (with my very rusty C skills) might be that you're just inputting the wrong string (not respecting the lettercase for example). Maybe you should try with much simpler strings first to already avoid that kind of possible mistake.

Comment: Wow. Full description of the problem, and even a link to ideone. Properly asked "help me debug" questions are so rare these days.

Comment: Too bad it's an exact duplicate. The duplicate isn't answered properly but the proposed fix is good.

Comment: Oh when I was typing this question I couldn't find any O.o so if something I will remove the question if someone asks I have no problem.

Comment: @arcanesorcerer , It is not necessary to delete the question when it is a duplicate.

Comment: @arcanesorcerer Don't delete the question the answers were good and just leave it like that

Comment: You need to call `fflush`

Comment: I will try next time to separate the code and debug after each statement.

Comment: I think this is because I was using scanf() all the time. And this was my first time using fgets() and I though there wouldn't be any problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`fgets` reads newline and put it in the buffer. So the string you type is never found in the array. Modify the code to suppress the newline after input, like this : `search_for[strlen(search_for)-1]='\0';`. That should work better.

Comment: Note that when doing *only* this, you better make sure you don't fill the buffer entirely or press EOF.

Comment: Should be `if(search_for[strlen(search_for)-1] == '\n') search_for[strlen(search_for)-1]='\0';`

Comment: Oh I will accept your answer soon and I want to say that this is the exact same source code from the book and I didn't knew about that so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Place this code before  calling the function.

```
search_for[strlen(search_for)-1]='\0';
```

You will get the correct output.